# Method-Override put request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-development-server

In my app.js, I required method-override and also `app.use(methodOverride("_method"))`

This

[image]

shows my error, what i've noticed is that the error does not include the ?_method=PUT like what's in the url.

This is my ejs file that is linked to my app.js

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style = "text-align: center;">Edit <%= campground.name %></h1>
        <div style = "width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form method = "POST" action ="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>?_method=PUT">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class = "form-control" type = "text" value="<%= campground.name %>" name = "campground[name]">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class = "form-control" type = "text" value="<%= campground.image %>" name = "campground[image]">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class = "form-control" type = "text" value="<%= campground.description %>" name = "campground[description]">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>">Go back</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

And this is my edit/update routes

```
//Edit campground route
router.get("/:id/edit", function(req, res){
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground){
       if(err){
           res.redirect("/campgrounds");
       } else{
           res.render("campgrounds/edit", {campground: foundCampground});
       }
    });

});
//Update campground route
router.post("/:id", function(req, res){
   Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.campground, function(err, updatedCampground){
      if(err){
          res.redirect("/campgrounds");
      } else{
          res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + req.params.id);
      }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: "what i've noticed is that the error does not include the ?_method=PUT like what's in the url" — That doesn't matter. It's clearly been recognised because the error message says it was trying to PUT the data.

Answer (score 1):

You've overridden the method type, so it is being treated as a PUT request.

You have `router.post("/:id",` but not `router.put("/:id",`.

Since you have no route that matches the URL and the method, you get the error.